# Understanding ArcSDE versioning tables?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, references, versioning

I have studied about ArcSDE schema and SDE tables in Oracle, MSSQL and also PostgreSQL. But after my research I still have many questions that I haven't been able to find out.

Initially I want you to take a look at this image.
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/002n/pdf/sdesystables_diagram.pdf

In this diagram you can see SDE tables, but the thing is we don't know when to reconcile/post/edit also move -whatever I want- how does *this mechanism work*?

As you can see on the diagram, there is no relationships in these tables. In fact they are, but we don't know what kind of relationship.

Comment: Give this a read: http://sspinnovations.com/blog/2011/06/01/versioning-dummies-part-1 I think it does a great job explaining. It's 4 parts, so be sure to read them all.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I read whole series. Until part 4. Also ı downloaded ther versioning book :) If you have another source please share with me.

Comment: This might be useful, there are some good questions: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/esritrainingmatters/2011/09/29/versioned-editing-seminar-your-questions-answered/ And if you REALLY want to understand (or not understand) versioning, then here's ESRI's white paper: http://support.esri.com/white-paper/721

Comment: Thanks. I've read these too :) But in these paper there is no relationships that ı want. I want any connections which additional explanations between tables. For example if I change one object, with tables are being affected and "how" ? We know delta tables and states things.. But example keysets and $ tables ? Not yet.

Comment: Part of the "relationship" logic and constraints of true ESRI geodatabases (those with an ArcSDE Repository) is actually not enforced at the database level, but at the application level (e.g. ArcMap / ArcGIS Pro). This means it is a very unwise idea to programmatically start changing or modifying ESRI geodatabases in an environment that is not geodatabase aware (so without the ArcObjects/ArcGIS Runtime or ArcGIS Pro SDK), or make modifications at the database level. ESRI does offer a few options for accessing (part of) the functionality and data of geodatabases via e.g. "Versioned Views".

Comment: I'm not talking about changing values or types as using "programmatically" as being "unwised". You got me completely wrong. I'm talking about "seeing and understanding" the relationships between tables. For example we know that sde_id in sde_table_locks means session_id in arcmap. But you think that I have been trying to change things on database views or 3rd app.. I just want you to look at that diagram above and tell me these tables relationships.